# How filter and delete object with null or empty property in json query

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, fetch, fetch-api

I have this json :

```
{
  "meta": {
    "status": 200,
    "pagination": {
      "page": 1,
      "perPage": 15,
      "hasNext": true
    }
  },
  "data": [
    { 
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Movie title1"
      "rating": null,
      "playProviders": [
        
      ]
    },
 { 
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Movie title2"
      "rating": {
        "ratingAssessment": "7.1"
      },
      "playProviders": [
        "HBO", "Netflix"
      ]
    }, 
   ....
}
```

I want to create a page with a list of movies, I need to fetch movies but only those which have a rating and playProviders, what parameters should I use in this request?
https://api.com/movies?orderBy=views

When I filters in the code:

```
programs.filter((program) => program.rating !== null);
```

it only gets a few films per page, those that don't have null. For example, 15 are per page and I get 2. How do I filter this? (I am using react typescript)
I don't have access to the API code. I need to filter what is returned by the API or write a query so that you get already filtered data from the API.

Comment: This looks like a paged request. So i assume it only returns 15 movies per request. Meaning client side filtering is pointless. If the api call is to fill only this 1 table, then just hardcode these null checks into the SQL query you are using to get the data from DB (i hope you are using DB). This is more of a API side filtering. Without know how your API works, i cant help you more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately this will not help. The problem is that I do not have access to the API code. I need to filter what is returned by the API or write a query so that you get already filtered data from the API.

Comment: In that case... i can only reccomend you to find some guide or documentation for the API endpoint. Maybe they have something you can use. Cause as far as i know there is no queryParams standard to filter null values. Or you cant do pageing and need to query for the entire list, then you can do client side filtering. But there is a danger of running out of memory if the list is too large.

Answer (score 0):

```js
programs = [
{rating: 1,
playProviders: ["sf"]
},
{
rating: 4,
playProviders: []
}
]
programs.filter(function(program) {
  if (program.rating !== null && program.playProviders.length !== 0) {
    return program;
  }
})
```